# Loading unmanaged DLL, from JAVA to C#

Tags: c#, java, dllimport

I have a Java application that has the following procedure (stripped to bare minimum):

```
public void connect()
{
   System.loadLibrary("asyncconn");

   pfcAsyncConnection.AsyncConnection_Connect(null, null, null, timeout);
}
```

In another class

```
package very.long.namespace.pfcAsyncConnection;

public class pfcAsyncConnection
{
  public static native AsyncConnection AsyncConnection_Connect(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, Integer paramInteger)
    throws jxthrowable;
}
```

I want to convert the Java code to C# and did this:

```
public void connect()
{
   pfcAsyncConnection.AsyncConnection_Connect(null, null, null, timeout);
}

public static class pfcAsyncConnection
{
    [DllImport("asyncconn.dll")]
    public static extern AsyncConnection AsyncConnection_Connect(String s1, String s2, String s3, Int32 i4);
}
```

It gives the error "Unable to find entry point named 'AsyncConncetion_Connect' in DLL asyncconn.dll"

The DLL is written in C/C++, I know method names may become mangled when compiled. Can anyone tell me if I I missed anything C# or I simply really loaded the wrong DLL? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Now I am able to call the method after checking `dumpbin \exports asyncconn.dll` to get the mangled name to be `very_long_namespace_AsyncConnection_1Connect()` Now the question is, what machanism does Java use to get build the method name?

Comment: What is the path in your "java.library.path"? Also, is that path in the Environment PATH?

Comment: I don't know the paths, so I copied all the DLL to my output folder. And if DLLImport an invalid dll file name, it will tell me file not found.

Comment: Try adding the path to the Windows PATH variable and point it to where the original path of the dll.

Comment: I finally managed to get the mangled method name and it calls correctly (although with error). I have hence updated the question to ask about Java LoadLibrary scheme.

Comment: you use `javah` on the class file to get a .h file. This file contains the name mangling that will be used for creating the function in the dll/.so

Comment: @Petesh thanks for the comment, I will investigate that.